# Generating a list of month names

Tags: php, date, mktime

Am am current facing a problem that need a solution ASAP.

I am trying to list all months of the year by using the following code:

```php
for ($m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++) {
    $month = date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m));
    echo $month . '<br/>';
}
```

But am getting the following unexpected output:

```
January
March
March
May
May
July
July
August
October
October
December
December
```

What am I doing wrong please help!!!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
     $month = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, date('Y')));
     echo $month. '<br>';
     }
```

Answer (score 11):

not as with mktime but equally powerful

```
$array = array("January", "February",.....);
for ($m=0; $m<12; $m++) {
     echo $array[$m]. '<br>';
     }
```

Comment: overlooked: `for($m=0;$m<12;$m++)`

Answer (score 7):

I guess you should loop it in this manner.

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
 echo date("F",strtotime(date("Y")."-".$i."-01"));
 echo "<br/>";
}
```

Or in your case, you want to use mktime()

```
for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12; $i++)
{
 echo date("F",mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,date("Y")));
 echo "<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Set `day` in `mktime()` to `1`, otherwise conversion is performed: `30.2.2012 = 1.3.2012`

```
$month = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m,1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Pay attention to the localization.

You can also use this

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'it_IT');
for($m=1;$m<=12;$m++){
  echo strftime("%B", mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 12));
}
```

Changing the parameter on the function setlocale() you can display the localized text.

[list of setlocale codes](http://download1.parallels.com/SiteBuilder/Windows/docs/3.2/en_US/sitebulder-3.2-win-sdk-localization-pack-creation-guide/30801.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but here is a different PHP 7+ `DateTime` based approach to get an array of month names:

```php
$monthSet = array_map(
    fn (int $m): string => (DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', "$m-1")->format('F')),
    range(1, 12),
);
```

Explanation:

- `range()` produces an array `[1...12`]
- `array_map()` runs the arrow function on each of these numeric months `$m`
- `createFromFormat()` is passed `$m` and `1` as the day (otherwise the day defaults to the current day and e.g. Feb-31 would overflow to the next month).

Answer (score -1):

If you use laravel

```
@for ($x = 1; $x <= 12; $x++)
<option value="{{$x}}">{{date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $x, 10))}}</option>
@endfor
```