# How to get all months in the year with Carbon using in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Im have a simple task as i think but im have some troble with this

Mb anyone know another way how to get all months of the year with Carbon using

In this sutiation im need only short name of month

At this time im have the next code

```
$items = [];
$startMonth = Carbon::now()->startOfYear()->format('M');
$endMonth = Carbon::now()->endOfYear()->format('M');
$monthRange = CarbonPeriod::create($startMonth, '1 month', $endMonth);
foreach ($monthRange as $month){
   $items[] = Carbon::parse($month)->format('M');
}
```

Are there any solutions without overwriting the variable $items

Thanks for help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829424/displaying-the-list-of-months-using-mktime-for-the-year-2012 ?

Comment: As in 1 year there are only/always12 months(1-12) it is pointless to use anything else then for loop 1 to 12.. eg "for ($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) {}"

Comment: Is there any reason you won't hardcode them? It's only 12 of them, unless there's a localisation requirement to fulfil

Comment: This is my desire and writing the correct business logic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$month = [];

for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
     $month[] = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, date('Y')));
}

print_r($month);
```

Answer (score 3):

One line solution:

```
array_map(fn($month) => Carbon::create(null, $month)->format('F'), range(1, 12))
```

`range(1, 12)` returns an array `[1, .., 12]`. Then, we're transforming each of the element to **full month name** using `Carbon`.