# how to get month list in array using php

Tags: php

I want to get the year-related months list into the array.
for an example:

$months = array(
'January',
'February',
'March',
'April',
'May',
'June',
'July ',
'August',
'September',
'October',
'November',
'December',
);

Comment: Please explain what is your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying the list of months using mktime for the year 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829424/displaying-the-list-of-months-using-mktime-for-the-year-2012)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) package to get the result

```
public function getMonthListFromDate(Carbon $start, Carbon $to): array
{
    $months = [];

    foreach (CarbonPeriod::create($start, '1 month', $to) as $month) {
        $months[] = $month->format('F');
    }

    return $months;
}
```

[image]